# Referenced assembly 'DocuSign.eSign' does not have a strong name

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to integrate Docusign with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 by trying to call the docusign API through a custom workflow. But when I am trying to build the project I am getting an error
Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'DocuSign.eSign' does not have a strong name

I tried the steps mentioned in the below link to sign a dll but still the same error.
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/341645/Referenced-assembly-does-not-have-a-strong-name

The project that I am adding this DLL to is a signed assembly as CRM needs a signed assembly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for [DocuSign C# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/) is available on Github.  You can build this source code with a strong name key.